# How to call a div with the same '.length' as the thumbnail I clicked on?

Tags: jquery

My page has divs holding big images (one is shown, the rest is hidden). My page also has a div showing thumbnails.

http://www.jordy.studio/paintings_new

After clicking on a thumbnail I'd like to **hide** the current big image and **show** the corresponding big image.

I'm quite new to jQuery. Navigating through the thumbnails works as I like:

```
// Slider
var divs = $('.expo');
divs.hide().first().show();
$("#next").click(function(e) {
   divs.eq(now).hide("slide", {
      direction: "left"
   }, 300);
   now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
   divs.eq(now).show("slide", {
      direction: "right"
   }, 300);
   updateCounter();
});
$("#prev").click(function(e) {
   divs.eq(now).hide("slide", {
      direction: "right"
   }, 300);
   now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
   divs.eq(now).show("slide", {
      direction: "left"
   }, 300);
   updateCounter();
});
// Thumbnails (click)
$('#thumbnails img').on('click', function() {
   $('#thumbnails img').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var pos = $(this).position().left;
   var currentscroll = $("#thumbnails").scrollLeft();
   var divwidth = $("#thumbnails").width();
   pos = (pos + currentscroll) - (divwidth / 2);
   $('#thumbnails').animate({
      scrollLeft: pos
   });
});
```

However, I am unsuccessfully trying to do the following:

On thumbnail click: get the .lenght of the thumbnail. Then *hide* current div with big painting image ('.expo') and after that *show* div with big image painting that has the same .lenght as the thumbnail that was clicked on.

I honestly don't know if this is even the way -_- yikes!

Would you say this is indeed the handiest approach in this case? What would a quicker / more efficient approach be? I'm eager to learn!

EDIT would it be easier if I give the thumbnails and images a similar class? or data attribute?

Comment: Not a good idea to preload all of those images (hidden elements are still loaded by the browser). If you have a database up and running I would suggest storing the filenames there and loading them dynamically (AJAX) when the thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: No database unfortunately, this website is all hard coded directly in html, it's a personal hobby project that grew out of hand... I would love to learn about and apply a database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to put an identifier on the thumbnails which will allow you to slide to the correct image.

You want to re-use this part of your prev and next function in your `$('#thumbnails img').on('click',...`:

```js
   divs.eq(now).hide("slide", {
      direction: "right"
   }, 300);

   now = **whatever the number of the thumbnail you clicked on is**;
   // now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;

   divs.eq(now).show("slide", {
      direction: "left"
   }, 300);
   updateCounter();
```

Your webpage is also loading all of the full-size images which are 50-100MB in total and take a few minutes to load.

To do a proper job of this, I'd suggest looking into dynamic loading and generating actual thumbnails on your server (so the client's downloading images that are only 100x100px, and a few KB each)

Comment: You are right the images are too big still -- I intend to change this. Dynamic loading is something I'm hoping to learn next! This will indeed be useful. Thanks for your time and effort.. now is there a way to calculate this bit by simply clicking on the thumbnail and get the length of the thumbnail and then add this length to the "now =" part? (they're the same) **whatever the number of the thumbnail you clicked on is**

Comment: @Jordy what do you mean `.length`? `.length` gives you the size of an array or the length of a string.

Comment: Sorry this is all a bit out of my comfort zone. I was hoping to show div ('.expo') number 30 after clicking on thumbnail number 30.... e.g. If I click on number 30 then I somehow hope to add "30" after the 'now = .... ' bit.

Comment: Will look into .index() this is something I haven't heard of before. I am close - yet so far away. Better get some sleep...Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll want to use `now = $(this).index()`, and the function in my answer should work. Maybe it's time to resurrect Superoboturbo :)

Comment: Hahaha not yet! He is still buried in the backyard of the academy. ;-) I found the problem I think, I have a double painting somewhere which messes up the counting.

Comment: You're better off using some sort of id on the paintings. You could have something like `data-thumbID="5"` on the thumbnail, and `data-paintingID="5"` on the relevant painting, then modify your function to be `$(".expo[data-paintingID=" + $(this).data("thumbID")).eq(now).show(...`

Comment: It's how you'd expect such a function to look if you were pulling your art from a database, or otherwise generating your page programmatically. It's also a method which is a bit more reusable (you can use it in other, more funky ways, in the future)

Comment: You are so right, I have never worked with a database. It's worth investing in. I shall educate myself on it. For now your help is highly appreciated. I have a fun 'slide up' for when a thumbnail is clicked. I'm as happy as I am sleepy. Thousand times thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the setup on your page you can show the big image corresponding to the thumbnails by using [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$("#thumbnails img").on("click", function() {
  let position = $("#thumbnails img").index(this);
  $("#big img").hide();
  $("#big img:eq(" + position + ")").show();
  $("#thumbnails img").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#big img {
  display:none;
}
#big img.show {
  display:block;
}
#thumbnails {
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big">
  <img class="show" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/cecece/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/e78765/fff">
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <img class="active" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/cecece/fff">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/e78765/fff">
</div>
```

If you want instead to avoid to have a page that contains so many large images, I suggest to switch to a solution using a data-attribute to store the location of the big image and load it when it is to be shown:

```js
$("#thumbnails img").on("click", function() {
  let big = $(this).attr("data-image");
  $("#big img").attr("src", big);
  $("#thumbnails img").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff">
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <img data-image="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000000/fff">
  <img data-image="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/cecece/fff" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/cecece/fff">
  <img data-image="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/e78765/fff" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/e78765/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try and implement this, it's all a bit much, was hoping there was a solution I would understand. Every day is a school day!

Comment: @Jordy Which part of my answer do you not understand? position = $("#thumbnails img").index(this) gets the number of the clicked image inside the collection of all thumbnail images and based on that the corresponding big image is selected.

Comment: I'm close. A combination of your answer, and the answer of @Joundill works:

$("#thumbnails img").on("click", function() {
    
    let position = $("#thumbnails img").index(this);

  divs.eq(now).fadeOut();

     now = position;

     divs.eq(now).fadeIn();
     
     updateCounter();

 });

Comment: http://jordy.studio/paintings_new however after scrolling through the thumbnails it brakes -_-

Comment: After scrolling the thumbnails section... Clicking on a thumbnail seems to get me the painting -1 (the painting before the one I clicked on)

Comment: @Jordy http://jordy.studio/paintings_new/ works for me, I get the big image corresponding to its thumbnail.

Comment: You are right, I have a double painting somewhere which breaks the counting up I believe.

Comment: @Jordy Yes, this image http://jordy.studio/paintings_new/img/2018_WC2_40x30.jpg is not the right image for the thumbnail and the right image for the thumbnail is shown on click of the next thumbnail.

Comment: Thank you Mattias, I'll educate myself on databases as you are right; that is the way to go. I should not spend nights hand typing html.. Thanks again for your time and effort!

Comment: @Jordy Glad that I was able to help :)